# Javascript onclick issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick, slider

I am having a problem with some code which I am trying to use as a basic image slider in google Chrome.

My HTML is as follows -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Gallery</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/gallery.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="wrapper">


    <div id="slider">
        <Img id="1" src="images/slide1.jpg">
        <Img id="2" src="images/slide 2.jpg">
        <Img id="3" src="images/slide 3.jpg">
    </div>

    <a href="#" class="left" onclick="prev(); return false;">Previous</a>
    <a href="#" class="right" onclick="next(); return false;">Next</a>


    </div>



    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/gallery.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

and this is my Javascript -

```
sliderInt=1;
sliderNext=2;

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#slider>img#1").fadeIn(300);
    startSlider();

});

function startSlider(){
    count=$("#slider>Img").size();

    loop=setInterval(function(){

        if(sliderNext>count){
            sliderNext=1;
            sliderInt=1;
        }

        $("#slider>Img").fadeOut(300);
        $("#slider>Img#" + sliderNext).fadeIn(300);

        sliderInt=sliderNext;
        sliderNext=sliderNext + 1;

    },3000);

}

function prev(){
    newSlide=sliderInt-1;
    showSlide(newSlide);
}

function next(){
    newSlide=sliderInt + 1;
    showSlide(newSlide);
}

function showSlide(){
    if(id>count){
        id=1;
    }else if(id<1){
        id=count;
    }

    $("#slider>Img").fadeOut(300);
    $("#slider>Img#" + id).fadeIn(300);

    sliderInt=id;
    sliderNext=id + 1;

}
```

However when I click the next/previous text, nothing happens.

Any advice?

PS. this is my first html and java attempt.

Many Thanks

Comment: make a fiddle for this .......

Comment: Please read [this](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console) then tell us what error it is showing.

Comment: what is id in function showSlide()

Comment: `slide 2.jpg` -> `slide2.jpg` ??

Comment: Make sure when you declare your variables you use `var` -- i.e. `var sliderInt = 1;`. Good coding practise.

Comment: I should add that the automatic image cycling works fine.

Comment: http://casb1.cloudapp.net/1016/1be61016ff9a717aa34c2adf7c5aa79e/3D%20Design/Gallery/gallery.html      that is the link

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8L5xA/
This is a fiddle with jquery, java, html and css.

Answer (score 1):

Open Google Chrome console (ctrl+shift+I), you'll see javascript error's.

1. It's bad idea, to use onclick attribute.
   You can use jQuery events.
   Something like that: $(".left").on("click", prev);
2. $("#slider>Img").fadeOut(300);
           $("#slider>Img#" + sliderNext).fadeIn(300);

It's wrong, because, second line will start before the first finished
Use this code:

```
$("#slider>Img").fadeOut(300);
setTimeout(function() {
    $("#slider>Img#" + sliderNext).fadeIn(300);
}, 300);
```

or

```
$.when( $("#slider>Img").fadeOut(300); )
 .done( $("#slider>Img#" + sliderNext).fadeIn(300); );
```

Answer (score 0):

I would remove the attribute for onclick on in the html for the buttons, 
and add a listner in jquery instead, since i feel its easier to keep all jquery/javascript in one place.

see fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/h25z9/

```
$(".right").click(function(){
   prev(); 
});
 $(".left").click(function(){
   next(); 
})
```

This doesnt work on jsfiddle since i dont have all resource, but you should see the changes i did to the code.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I have altered the code as your suggested but I'm not seeing any change in my result :/

Comment: Do you get anything in the console? (F12)

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: id is not definced
event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault()
Uncaught ReferenceError: id is not definced

Comment: Ok, these errors are covered in other answers. please submit a new question with these errors since they do not belong in "Javascript onclick issue"

Answer (score 0):

setInterval does not get count variable. The startSlider runs, inits the setInterval and ends. The count is not saved in more global postion eg outside the function. It is destroyed as the funciont ends. So instead above code, you should either:

```
var count = 0;

function startSlider(){
}
```

OR

```
setInterval(function(count){

        if(sliderNext>count){
            sliderNext=1;
            sliderInt=1;
        }

        $("#slider>Img").fadeOut(300);
        $("#slider>Img#" + sliderNext).fadeIn(300);

        sliderInt=sliderNext;
        sliderNext=sliderNext + 1;

    },3000, count);
```

If it still does not work, you have problem with you might have a problem with your logic.